# How to create a distance calculating webpage from php js using google maps

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps

Hey I want to create a page for a business in which many service centers are connected and they all will be assigned a work according to their pin codes and we will get complaints from the customers and according to customers pin code we will alot a service center. Now i want to calculate the distance between center and customers address and give the bill according to the distance for example the service charge is 20INR for per service inside 2km radius if the customers address is far from 2km then every km will have 10INR extra charge are there any examples by which i can do that in php &  mysql and i also want to store service center's all transaction details in database is there any way i can do that?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: i am thinking to manipulate google maps api to calculate distance between both pin codes. and then set some values for each KM.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can store in DB and search with calculating the distance with PHP. Search can be slow if amount of centers is huge, so you will need to handle it with MySql preprocession.  Here is a code I wrote long time ago to calculate a distance with PHP.

```
 $lat = '50.45466';
 $lng =  '30.5238';
 $lat1 = '50.3382';
 $lng1 =  '30.8939';


$R = 6371;
                        $f1 = deg2rad(floatval($lat));
                        $f2 = deg2rad(floatval($lat1));
                        $df = deg2rad(floatval($lat1 - $lat));
                        $dl = deg2rad(floatval($lng1 - $lng));
                        $a = sin($df / 2) * sin($df / 2) +
                            cos($f1) * cos($f2) *
                            sin($dl / 2) * sin($dl / 2);
                        $c = 2 * atan2(sqrt($a), sqrt(1 - $a));

                        $dist = $R * $c;
```

Result is 29.256084031488 km